# Read values using `backticks` instead of Pipe | C++

Tags: c++, linux, shell

on shell there is the possibility to give a output to another programm using a Pipe.

for example :::

```
ps axu | grep someprocess
```

Now i want to programme a C++ Programme that accepts those Pipes too.

I found a solution like.

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string mypipe;
    if(cin);
    {
        cin >> mypipe;
        cout << mypipe << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now i want, that i am able to call my function with using backticks.

for example i am using a shell construct like this.

```
./myprog.bin `./otherprog.bin someparameter`
```

How can i read the output that otherprog.bin generates into my Programm using Parameters instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add commandline parameters to your main function, like this:

```
int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
```

`argc` is the argument count, `argv` the table that holds them.